# authenticate play 1.2.x application running on separate server from another play 1.2.x application implemented with secure module

Tags: playframework-1.x

I have developed a play 1.2.5 application and implemented secure module module for authentication.Its working fine. Now I have developed another play 1.2.5 application which is running on a separate server. I have maintained a href tag in my first play application which has the link to second application.On loging in through my first application, I want the username to be passed to the second application because i am using the logged username. As soon as I log out from the first application, The session (username) should be removed from the second application too.

How can i achieve this ...Plz help!

Comment: This would leave a huge hole in your security, because anyone could spoof a request like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you run both of servers on 1 domain (such as www.example.com), and using load balancer (like nginx) to transfer requests to 2 server. You just make sure the config `application.secret` is the same for both.

If you run on different sub-domain (Recommend), you MUST do like that:

1. Server should use sub-domain, for example login server is login.example.com and application server is app.example.com
2. Use config `application.defaultCookieDomain=.example.com` for both server, then they can use the cookie each others
3. Make sure both servers have same config `application.secret`

If you really want to put 2 difference domain, like example.com and example.net. You should implement OAuth on login server and provide API to call from application server.